# How to list users and groups with Powershell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, group-policy, uac, user-groups

How can I list local groups?

```
PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir> Get-WMIObject win32_operatingsystem


SystemDirectory : C:\WINDOWS\system32
Organization    : Microsoft
BuildNumber     : 17134
RegisteredUser  : thufir
SerialNumber    : 00330-62820-00000-AAOEM
Version         : 10.0.17134



PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir> get-LocalGroupMember
get-LocalGroupMember : The term 'get-LocalGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-LocalGroupMember
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-LocalGroupMember:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir> get-LocalGroup
get-LocalGroup : The term 'get-LocalGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-LocalGroup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-LocalGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir>
```

Running `compmgmt.msc` will bring up a GUI listing local users and groups, of course.  This is from a Surface 3.

I've tried solutions from:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/4548476/262852

------edit-------------

looks to be configuration issue as discussed in the comments:

PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir> Get-LocalGroup -Name "Administrators"
Get-LocalGroup : The term 'Get-LocalGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-LocalGroup -Name "Administrators"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LocalGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir>
PS C:\Users\thufir>

Comment: Just to be sure, you tried *all* the solutions in that SO post and none worked?

Comment: The accepted answer from your link works for me on Windows 7. What error message do you get when you try it?

Comment: @DavidPostill - The accepted answer appears to only be applicable to local users.  However, `Get-LocalGroup -Name "Administrators"` should absolutely work for the author, if it isn't then something else is going on.  The fact they are being told it's not recognized indicates their underline problem is a configuration problem.

Comment: @Ramhound `Get-LocalGroup -Name "Administrators"` doesn't work for me either on Win 7 (Powershell version 5.0)

Comment: OK so that should work in Win 10.

Comment: @DavidPostill - `get-LocalGroupMember` requires PowerShell 5.1.  WMF 5.1 would need to be installed for it to work on Windows 7.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. 5.1 installed and all working as expected.